# How can I remove the white square around my NSProgressIndicator?

Tags: macos, cocoa, menubar, nsmenuitem, nsprogressindicator

I'm adding an NSProgressIndicator to my NSMenuItem (with a custom view). It works fine, but it has a weird square around it:

[image: White square around progress indicator]

Here is my code:

```
// In my @interface declaration:
NSProgressIndicator *_spinner;

...

// In initWithFrame:
_spinner = [[NSProgressIndicator alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 20, 20)];
[_spinner setBezeled:NO];
[_spinner setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[_spinner setControlSize:NSMiniControlSize];
[_spinner setStyle:NSProgressIndicatorSpinningStyle];
[_spinner sizeToFit];
[self addSubview:_spinner];
```

I am not sure why this is happening. Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the superview (`self` in the snippet)? How does it draw itself?

Comment: @KenThomases The superclass is an NSView.

Comment: Hey did you solve this? I have same problem too.

Comment: @devxoul Unfortunately I have not. :(

Answer (score 2):

Me too faced the same issue, 
The problem is not with the progress indicator, it is with the associated superview of the progress indicator.

The Solution is,

Just change the **Appearance** property value of the **View** to **"Aqua"** instead of "Inherited Aqua". Refer the attached image.

[image: Refer this Image]

Answer (score -3):

Try making the background transparent and making the view not opaque

```
[_spinner setOpaque:NO];
[_spinner setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: Unfortunately NSProgressIndicator does not have those methods.